# Telnet connection to Android-x86 through VirtualBox

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtual-machine, telnet, virtualbox

I successfully installed "**android-x86-2.2-generic**" in a VirtualBox machine. I took the iso from here: http://code.google.com/p/android-x86/downloads/detail?name=android-x86-2.2-generic.iso

Everything is working properly, even the network (FYI: Bridge with PCnet-PCI II).

I'm using it to have a faster emulator (and it **really** is), and now I need to simulate SMS and Missing Call. Usually in AVD emulator I use a telnet session to localhost:5555/n. But in the VirtualBox, even if I connect to 192.168.1.4:5555/n nothing is working, only a black screen.

I don't even know if it is possible to use telnet on Android-x86... do you know? Is there an other way to simulate SMS and Missing Call without telnet connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The telnet control port is only available on the android sdk emulator. Android X86 is an actual OS build for devices (can be used also on virtual machines), and does not have this control interface available.

ADB bridge over network is however enabled on these builds, so you can connect the ADB from the host machine by using "adb connect IPADDRESS" command (where the IPADDRESS is the current IP address of the android x86 machine).

I recomend [this](http://blogs.nuxeo.com/dev/2011/10/speeding-up-the-android-emulator.html) blog entry on how to futher adapt the Android x86 running VM to be closer to an actual user device (e.g. phone).

Comment: Well it's 3 years old, so that product in the mean time become [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)