# How can I emulate SMS and Telephony on Android-x86?

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtual-machine

I have installed Android-x86 on VirtualBox and setting the `adb connect 10.0.2.15` successfully.
Now, I wanna emulate SMS and Telephony to the VM using Emulator Control, but the Emulator Control being disabled. Can I do SMS and Telephony emulation on the VM? How to do it?

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Telnet connection to Android-x86 through VirtualBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740947/telnet-connection-to-android-x86-through-virtualbox)