# How to emulate SMS on Android-x86 on virtualbox?

Tags: android, sms, android-x86

So the title basically speaks for itself. I've seen other posts about this problem but seems like no one answers to it. Anyway, I'd like to send SMS to Android-x86 on the virtualbox, something like telnet it? Just like how you can do it using the traditional AVD.

AVD emulator runs really slow on my machine as I'm using a Windows 7 and AMD Athlon II with only 3GB. And as you can read online, speeding up requires an Intel supporting VT-x. Any thought would be much appreciated. thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Telnet connection to Android-x86 through VirtualBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740947/telnet-connection-to-android-x86-through-virtualbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following threads on the Android-x86 Google Group.  I have never done SMS with Android-x86, but here is a synthesis of some things from the group.  I am guessing that it cannot be done.  Also, you should see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740947/telnet-connection-to-android-x86-through-virtualbox).

From [Telnet connection to Android-x86](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/android-x86/sms/android-x86/Qh7sc7ihCyY/AOm7XFRKLm0J):

> ...should be able to connect to "telnet 192.168.1.XXX 5555" and send 
>   "sms send 555123456 SMS_text_here" to simulare an SMS, but the telnet 
>   connection is not working....

No responses.

From [android x86 telnet connection](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/android-x86/SMS/android-x86/XHmT2PrSa1k/APoeuMuTT5gJ):

> ... So I was wondering, are there in a 
>   plans to make it more as an emulator stuff for developing purposes ? I 
>   mean telnet connection simmulating sms'es...

No responses.