# how do you send a text message to androidx86 emulator in virtual box?

Tags: android, text, virtualbox

I am trying to have my Android x86 virtual box receive a mock SMS message. This is similar to the DDMS sending a text message but I'm using VirtualBox emulator, not Android Studio or Eclipse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to emulate SMS on Android-x86 on virtualbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471366/how-to-emulate-sms-on-android-x86-on-virtualbox)